# PHP Session and JavaScript window.location.replace

Tags: php, javascript, session

My use of:

```
window.location.replace("calendar.php");
```

Seems to be not working at all with my PHP session variables. When I use this call I can not use the back button with my code:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != TRUE) {
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
?>
```

Does anyone know why this may be? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? The whole point of a replace would be to replace an instance in window.history, so the last page would be replaced with the new one, and the back button would no longer work the way it usually does.

Comment: You are right, but it's not helping him !

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `window.location.href = "calendar.php";` instead. That should hang on to your session variables, as well as not breaking the back button.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you do have :

- **window.location.replace("calendar.php");**

but also

-**window.location.assign("calendar.php");**

the first one might clear the session while the second will keep it.